# Schedule JPA query and access result in a CDI-bean?

Tags: jpa-2.0, cdi

Every x minutes I want to query for new instances and cache the results. I currently only need a simple cache solution so I would like to update a `Set` in my `@ApplicationScoped` `CacheBean`

I tried a:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture<?> sf = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
//.................
```

But the thread created couldn't access any contextual instances (InvocationException).

So how to do this the CDI/JPA way?

Using Tomcat 7, Weld, JPA2 - Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with David Blevins for a good while I can acknowledge his answer as a great one that I voted up. Big thanks for all that. All though David you forgot to announce your involvement in TomEE which I know always bother someone.

Anyways the solution I went for was suggested by Mark Struberg in #Deltaspike (freenode).

As a deltaspike user I was pleased to do it with deltaspike. Solution is outlined in this blog post:

http://struberg.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/controlling-cdi-containers-in-se-and-ee/

I had to switch into OWB see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-284

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to try the version of Tomcat with CDI and JPA already integrated ([TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org)).  It comes with OpenJPA but you can use Hibernate.  Then do your caching with a class like this:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class CachingBean {

    @Resource 
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    @Schedule(minute = "*/10", hour = "*")
    private void run() {
        // cache things
    }
}
```

That component would automatically start when the app starts and would run the above method every ten minutes.  See the [Schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) docs for details.

### UPDATE

Hacked up an example for you.  Uses a nice CDI/EJB combination to schedule CDI Events.

Effectively this is a simple wrapper around the `BeanManager.fireEvent(Object,Annotations...)` method that adds `ScheduleExpression` into the mix.

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class Scheduler {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Resource
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    public void scheduleEvent(ScheduleExpression schedule, Object event, Annotation... qualifiers) {

        timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule, new TimerConfig(new EventConfig(event, qualifiers), false));
    }

    @Timeout
    private void timeout(Timer timer) {
        final EventConfig config = (EventConfig) timer.getInfo();

        beanManager.fireEvent(config.getEvent(), config.getQualifiers());
    }

    // Doesn't actually need to be serializable, just has to implement it
    private final class EventConfig implements Serializable {

        private final Object event;
        private final Annotation[] qualifiers;

        private EventConfig(Object event, Annotation[] qualifiers) {
            this.event = event;
            this.qualifiers = qualifiers;
        }

        public Object getEvent() {
            return event;
        }

        public Annotation[] getQualifiers() {
            return qualifiers;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, have `Scheduler` injected as an EJB and schedule away.

```
public class SomeBean {

    @EJB
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    public void doit() throws Exception {

        // every five minutes
        final ScheduleExpression schedule = new ScheduleExpression()
                .hour("*")
                .minute("*")
                .second("*/5");

        scheduler.scheduleEvent(schedule, new TestEvent("five"));
    }

    /**
     * Event will fire every five minutes
     */ 
    public void observe(@Observes TestEvent event) {
        // process the event
    }

}
```

Full source code and working example, [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/schedule-events/).

### You must know

- CDI Events are not multi-treaded

If there are 10 observers and each of them take 7 minutes to execute, then the total execution time for the one event is 70 minutes.  It would do you absolutely no good to schedule that event to fire more frequently than 70 minutes.

What would happen if you did?  Depends on the `@Singleton` `@Lock` policy

- `@Lock(WRITE)` is the default.  In this mode the `timeout` method would essentially be locked until the previous invocation completes.  Having it fire every 5 minutes even though you can only process one every 70 minutes would eventually cause all the pooled timer threads to be waiting on your Singleton.
- `@Lock(READ)` allows for parallel execution of the `timeout` method.  Events will fire in parallel for a while.  However since they actually are taking 70 minutes each, within an hour or so we'll run out of threads in the timer pool just like above.

The elegant solution is to use `@Lock(WRITE)` then specify some short timeout like `@AccessTimeout(value = 1, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)` on the `timeout` method.  When the next 5 minute invocation is triggered, it will wait up until 1 minute to get access to the Singleton before giving up.  This will keep your timer pool from filling up with backed up jobs -- the "overflow" is simply discarded.

Comment: While we have TomEE under investigation we are not yet ready for a switch.

I will add openEJB to the class path and if it doesn't work remove weld since openEJB uses has a dependency to openwebbeans impl :(

Comment: If you grab the "tomee" drop in war file (formerly called the openejb.war) and add that to Tomcat 7 it should work.

Comment: Why do you declare BeanManager as a resource? I am not that familiar with EJB since I don't use it at all.

Are you preposing that when I have my data I manipulate the beanManager in order to expose it to CDI-beans?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to test this further until later. I found this now when you introduced @Schedule for me so I have hopes for something great here.

http://alpengeist-de.blogspot.se/2011/10/cdi-events-solve-fancy-problems_21.html

http://www.andygibson.net/blog/tutorial/getting-started-with-jsf-2-0-and-cdi-part-3/

Comment: While what David is suggesting is good, it still won't work. Because you're doing it in a scheduler you're not guaranteed to actually have any of the built-in contexts available save ApplicationScoped. If you're trying to get to any other scopes it won't work.

Comment: ApplicationScoped and RequestScoped are guaranteed and tested in the CDI TCK for EJB timer methods.

Comment: I couldn't get tomEE nor openEJB working tried for a few hours and had some contact with the list, had a few resonses so will see you it goes.

Comment: @LightGuard So you are basically saying that this can't be done? If so I will probably start looking for another direction in my career :P

I think this is a basic demand it surprises me that this is so hard.

Comment: Thanks David, didn't know they tested RequestScoped as well, that makes sense now that I think about it. Karl: Listen to what David has to say. Keep things either DependentScoped, ApplicationScoped or RequestScoped and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing new Runnable() {....} into scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate rather create a CDI bean that implements Runnable and @Inject that bean and then pass it to scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate

Comment: Have you tested that? Afaik that has no change of working.

As put by Struberg in one of his blogs:

 The problem is obvious: no servlet-request means that there is no Servlet Context for the Thread!

Comment: Your question states the bean is application scope, you could @Inject into your servlet listener as the application scope is always active?